# ¿como almaceno valores dentro de un ciclo anidado?

Tags: c++, bucles

**Explico mi problema: el funcionamiento consiste en lanzar mil valores al azar entre 1 y 100; luego almacenar en un contador los valores menores a 13. Todo eso lo tengo listo. El problema viene cuando tengo que repetir este ciclo otras 10.000 veces por lo tanto necesito 10.000 valores de este contador. Pero no se hacer esto ultimo :C **

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main(){
    int num, c; 
    int contador=0;
    srand(time(NULL));   
    
    for(int j = 0; j < 10000; j++){ //En este ciclo tengo problemas
        for(c =0 ; c <= 1000; c++){
            num = 1 + rand() % (101 - 1); //Nuestro rango, Número aleatorios entre 1 y 100.
            /*cout << num<<endl;  Imprimir valores en pantalla, solo por motivos pedagogicos.*/
            
            if (num <= 13 ){ //contabilizamos los valores menores a 13.
                contador = contador +1;
            } 
        }
    }
    
    cout<<"el numero total es:"<<contador<<endl; //Se muestra en pantalla el resultado.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Utiliza un arreglo de contadores de 10000 elementos: int contadores[10000]={0}; Cuando salgas del segundo `for` metes el contador la arreglo utilizando como índice la variable `j`: contadores[j]=contador; Importante: antes del segundo `for` pon el contador a 0: contador=0; Al final con un for imprimes todos los contadores del arreglo.

Comment: Generalmente los índices empiezan en 0 uno menos que la cantidad.  Tus ciclos deberían ser  j=0; j<10000 para que cojas los 10000

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices pero ¿como puedo hacer lo de reiniciar el contador?

Answer (score 0):

utiliza una variable que lleve el conteo de repeticiones del ciclo; adicionalmente una validación en la que pregunte si llego a 10000 vuelva a contar pero de 1000 a 2000 y asi sucesivamente un ejemplo seria algo como esto

```
    int n = 10000, j = 1;
    int cont = 0;
    for(int j = j; j <= n; j++){ //<---
         // incrementa el contador 
         cont = j+1;
         
        }
 // valida el contador
         if(cont == n){
             // aqui duplicas el valor de n para repetir el ciclo
              n = cont*2;
         }
```

Espero haberte ayudado

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un array:

```
int contador[10000];

for(int j = 0; j < 10000; j++){ //En este ciclo tengo problemas
    for(c =0 ; c <= 1000; c++){
        num = 1 + rand() % (101 - 1); //Nuestro rango, Número aleatorios entre 1 y 100.
        /*cout << num<<endl;  Imprimir valores en pantalla, solo por motivos pedagogicos.*/
        
        if (num <= 13 ){ //contabilizamos los valores menores a 13.
            contador[j]++;
        } 
    }
}
```

O también puedes usar un contenedor de la STL:

```
std::array<int, 10000> resultados;

for(int j = 0; j < resultados.size(); j++){ //En este ciclo tengo problemas
    for(c =0 ; c <= 1000; c++){
        num = 1 + rand() % (101 - 1); //Nuestro rango, Número aleatorios entre 1 y 100.
        /*cout << num<<endl;  Imprimir valores en pantalla, solo por motivos pedagogicos.*/
        
        if (num <= 13 ){ //contabilizamos los valores menores a 13.
            contador[j]++;
        } 
    }
}
```